# Problem querying AWS Athena from Lambda introducing a variable

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need help on a little problem that I have with my AWS Lambda function. This function queries my AWS Athena database.
The code looks like this :

```
import json
import boto3
import time



def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('athena')

    QueryResponse = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString = "MY QUERY;",
        QueryExecutionContext = {
            'Database' : 'myDatabase'
        },
        ResultConfiguration = {
            'OutputLocation' : 's3://mys3Bucket'
        }
    )


    #Oberserve results :
    queryId = QueryResponse['QueryExecutionId']
```

The code works great, but I am having some troubles with the "WHERE" part of my sql query (that is a long one)
Here is the part of my Query :

```
WHERE x.id_date > cast(date_format(date_trunc('day', current_timestamp - 
interval '3' day), '%Y%m%d') as integer)
and x.id_date <= cast(date_format(current_timestamp, '%Y%m%d') as integer)
and c.label = 'NAME'
```

My query is written on a single line to fit the Python code replacing "MY QUERY".

Le problem is :
I need to replace the 'NAME' part by a variable (string) that will be given to my Lambda. I tried to use %s to replace by the given variable, but as there is '%Y%m%d' in my query, the code is waiting for string to replace these part too, but it is just made to format the date as I want to. I tried to replace NAME by a string and it works perfectly so I know my query is not the problem. I tried to put 'c.label = '%s' in first to see if it the % method would simply replace the first %s and let the other ones do their job but it didn't work.

So my question is : How can I replace 'NAME' by a str variable ?can I do this keeping my query on a single line ? (if yes, how ?) or at least how can I divide my query in different lines I could interact with ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use then f-string.

Comment: Well yes thank you, I didn't know the other ways to use f-string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comment, the solution was to use :

```
MyString = 'my string to replace in query'
QueryString = f"SELECT * FROM {MyString};"
```